# AngularJS change in directive's scope not updating parent controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
    <test ng-if="toggle" props="condition"></test>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.condition = [true];
    $scope.toggle = $scope.condition[0];
    $scope.$watch('condition', (newv, oldv, scope) => {
        console.log('old: ' + oldv);
        console.log('new: ' + newv);
        console.log('toggle: ' + scope.toggle);
    }, true);
}]);

myApp.directive("test", function() {
   return {
       template: '<div>directive show</div>',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           props: "="
       },
       controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
           $scope.props[0] = false;
       }]
   }
});
```

The behavior is that after `condition[0]` is changed by directive to false, I can see the new value in console log, but `toggle` is not updating.

**My question is**:
Why `toggle` is not updating when `condition[0]` is changed? Why the digest cycle does not update `toggle` as well? Or does the digest cycle even update `toggle` at all when its assigned value changed?

And I am NOT asking for a solution to this problem but the cause of this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, your question looks like this:

```js
var a = false;
var b = a;
console.log(a,b);
var b = true;
console.log(a,b);
```

Why is `a` not `true` after the second `console.log`?
Shouldn't `a` and `b` be the same?

No, because `a` and `b` are separate entities.

Similarly, when the code assigns the value `false` to `$scope.props[0]` in the directive's scope it is bound to `$scope.condition[0]` of the parent scope.

`$scope.toggle` and `$scope.condition[0]` are separate entities. `a` does not change when `b` changes.

`$scope.toogle` does not change when `$scope.condition[0]` changes.

---

> Why the digest cycle does not update toggle as well? Or does the digest cycle even update toggle at all when its assigned value changed?

The `ng-if="toggle"` directive creates a watch on `$scope.toggle`. It never modifies `$scope.toggle`.

The `props="condition"` binding creates a watch on `$scope.props` of the directive and updates the value of `$scope.condition` of the parent `$scope`. Because it is a two-way binding, it also places a watch on `$scope.condition` of the parent and updates the `$scope.props` property of the directive.

The `$scope.toggle` property is never updated by the AngularJS framework or its digest cycle.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question to be clearer. Why the digest cycle does not update `toggle` as well? Or does the digest cycle even update `toggle` at all when its assigned value changed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `replace: true` in the directive's config.

when using `replace: true`, it will replace the directive tag with the content, so you will lose the `ngIf` directive as the initial value for `toggle` is `true`.

```
<test ng-if="toggle" props="condition"></test>
```

will be replaced with

```
 <div>directive show</div>
```

So the result will be

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller">
  <div>directive show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it would lose the `ng-if`. And I'm asking for the cause of this problem, not a solution. Thanks!